# git show modification of a function between two commits

Tags: git, function, methods, history

To show a function modification history, I can use `git log -L :functionName:filePath`.

But it'll show all the modification history of the function, which may be too lang.

How can I just get modification of the function between two specific commit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get one solution from [Advanced Git log](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-log) with `git log commit1..commit2 -L :functionName:filePath`